# MVC view with ajax updating partial views, back button issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a view containing four dropdown lists that act as filters for the resulting list of matching product items, each getting updated via ajax with partial views except for the first one.  The first dropdown list is pre-populated when the view is first rendered, with the remaining being refreshed as the user selects an item from the "parent" dropdown.  As an item in the final dropdown list is selected, another partial view is filled via another ajax call to display the results of the filtering.

All of this works fine except for if the user navigates to another page, then uses the Back button to return to this page.  When coming back, the only list with data is the first dropdown.

I can easily use a jQuery `$(document).ready` to repopulate the lists, except to do this, I need the values that were previously selected in each dropdown list in order to restore the lists to the way the user left them.  The problem is, only the first dropdown list (the one that is NOT populated with ajax) is the only one that I can get the previously selected value from.  All others have a value of "null".

How can I retrieve/preserve the values of the other dropdown lists so that I can reset everything when returning to the page?  I have seen many posts concerning similar issues, but all of them appear to deal with postbacks, which are not the problem here, from what I can tell.

Data Model:

```
public class ATVApplicationsPageModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<iplItem> IplItemList { get; set; }
    public string SelectedMake { get; set; }
    public string SelectedModel { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPolarisCode { get; set; }
    public string SelectedProductGroup { get; set; }
    public string SelectedYear { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Makes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Models { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> PolarisCodes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ProductGroups { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Years { get; set; }
}
```

Code for Makes dropdown list (main parent dropdown):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMake, Model.Makes, new { @class = "ATVMakeDropDown form-control", onchange = "getYears();"})
```

Code for Years partial view:

```
@model nhcdist.com.Models.ATVApplicationsPageModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedYear, Model.Years, new { @class = "ATVYearDropDown form-control", onchange = "getModels();" })
```

The other partial views are the same as the Years partial view, just using the appropriate list information.

For the dropdown lists, the cascade order is Makes, Years, Models, PolarisCodes, then ProductGroups.

JavaScript for updating each partial:

```
function getYears() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Products/RefreshATVYearList",
        data: { Make: $("#SelectedMake").find(":selected").text() }
    })

   .done(function (data) {
       $("#YearList").html(data);
       getModels();
   })
}
```

Each javascript function updates the corresponding dropdown list, then calls the next javascript function in the cascading chain to send the selected value in that dropdown list and update the next dropdown list following it in the order.  As with the views, each dropdown has its own javascript function, like the getYears() function, above, just concerning data for its own dropdown.

Comment: You could serialize the fields and send them via ajax to the server on page unload. When the server gets the variables you can store them via cookies or session. Then check for them on page load and repopulate the data.

Comment: Are you not able to store the user's choices in a session variable? Every time they make a change you are hitting the server which you could then store that value to a property on a session variable.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  I'll try storing the selections in cookies as I'm already using that for other information.